# Cannot import python3-requests, though it is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

On `Debian 10`, when I try to import `requests`, I get:

```
$ python3 -c 'import requests'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

However, `requests` module is installed:

```
$ dpkg -L python3-requests
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py
...
```

Also, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` is in path:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.path)'
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.7/dist-packages']
```

I found out, that, if I `pip3`-install requests as `root`, I can import requests.

But why can python not import the (debian) packages from `python3-requests`?

Btw, I am having the same problem with package `python3-gi` where I can not `import gi`.

I think something is very broken...

Comment: You may want to just consider using virtual environments rather than fight with system packages.

Comment: I cannot use `virt-manager`, because I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for `requests` and `gi`. However, if I do `apt-get install virt-manager`, I expect `virt-manager` to run without any virtual environments.

Comment: virt-manager is not what I mean- those are virtual machines, but virtual environments are very different.

Virtual Environments are folders that contain all of the packages for a single project. I'd suggest [reading up on them](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) as they likely solve your problems.

Comment: I am totally aware of that. Let me rephrase my problem: I start a programm which I installed through `apt`. I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named requests`. (By the way the program happens to be `virt-manager` which has nothing to do with virtual environments).

Comment: I do not understand why I (or `virt-manager`) cannot import `requests` though it is in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the "solution"... Though `dpkg -L` suggests an installation in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests` there is no such file:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests
ls: Zugriff auf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I had to do

```
apt-get --reinstall install python3-requests
```

If `--reinstall` is left out, it won't work. Strange.